# htaccess mod_rewrite consolidation

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to consolidate the following two lines into a single line ?

```
RewriteRule . /pages/article.php [L]
RewriteRule $ /pages/article.php [L]
```

Since it is a similar issue (consolidation of htaccess directives), I also need assistance consolidating the following into a single line as well :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com$" locally_linked=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you _intend_ to match with these? Since neither is `^` anchored, both have extremely broad matching possibilities. The first will match anything with at least one character, while the second will match _anything at all_, with or without any characters. (They can be combined certainly, but it would help to know the intent)

Comment: The intention is to match everything from root forward.  Adding the ^ in front messes this up on cPanel subdomains.  Essentially, it's everything in current path (eg website root) forward -- match everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `RewriteRule` directives can be combined, mainly because the second doesn't do anything especially  useful.  The `$` anchor will *always* be present in the input string, so that rule matches *any input*.  The first rule only has a single `.` which matches any one character, but since it has no `^$` anchors, that one character can be anywhere in the string.

Essentially the sum of these two is to match any string with or without a character. That can be reduced to:

```
RewriteRule .* /pages/article.php [L]
```

The `.*` will match zero or more characters, but not capture them for reuse in a variable. There's no real need to test the `$` anchor.

---

The `SetEnvIfNoCase` can be all combined if you make use of an optional grouping `()?` and make the trailing slash optional with `/?`. This should match all 4 possibilities, since the `www.` is made optional, and the trailing `/` is optional.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://(www\.)?example\.com/?$" locally_linked=1
```

Note, I have escaped the `.` in the regular expression since they are otherwise interpreted as metacharacters, even though technically the also match the literal `.` And the double quotes surrounding the regular expression should not actually be needed, but aren't harmful either.

Comment: You are a wizard with this.  The SetEnvIfNoCase -- can tell without testing it that it works.   The RewriteRule on the other hand, I believe I encountered the same problems when using .*  ...  give me a few minutes and I will run a couple tests to see if I can reproduce the issue (issue was it was skipping the home page) ...

Comment: One last thing on this..... suppose i have multiple domain extensions .....     (for EnvIfNoCase),  aka,  com, net, org, ca .  How would that be written in the `\.com` segment ?

Comment: Separate them with `|` to make a logical "or" group, like `^http://(www\.)?example\.(com|org|net|biz|info|co|ca)/?$`

Comment: So much more elegant.   You don't know how much I love you right now ---  my htaccess files were a bloody mess XD  ... did the trick, but every time I go to modify them it's like 200+ lines long XD

Comment: A lot of people think regular expressions are black magic, but eventually you can internalize a couple of important concepts that make this easier.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an excellent site to learn.

Comment: Lets go to live chat pls :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61717/discussion-between-sanuel-jackson-and-michael-berkowski).